# Jenkins HTML publishing on build level without copies

Tags: jenkins, html-reports-jenkins

I am trying to **publish HTML reports for each build**. I tried plugin [HtmlPublisher (1.22)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) but when it publishes my reports on their build page (using `keepAll=true`), it creates copies of reports from all previous builds in each build directory. So, each Jenkins build includes many copies of old reports and they are bigger and bigger. If I publish my reports on the project page (using `keepAll=false`), old reports are preserved in their project directory (in my file system) but only the last report is accessible from Jenkins. Is there any way how to have reports **on their build pages without creation of their duplicates**? Maybe, there is some parameter that I'm still missing.

My pipeline includes the following HtmlPublisher use:

```
publishHTML (target: [
  allowMissing: false,
  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
  keepAll: true,
  reportDir: "./htmlReports",
  reportFiles: reportFileNames, //generic variable
  reportName: "Results"
])
```

EDIT: It seems that the publishHTML publishes the whole directory (`reportDir`) not the files (`reportFiles`). The files are used only for publishing wrapper (HTML generated by the publishHTML). So, when I generate my HTML artifacts to a shared directory for all builds, all files from this shared directory are copied to the build directory during publishing.

Is there way how I can publish only specific files without archiving all files in directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess that copying of the whole directory is because of possible resources of published HTML pages. Therefore, all files are archived to (build/project) directory.

The htmlPublisher provides optional parameter **includes** which allows to specify the archived files.